# Load a cursor stored in the resources file C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

IDE: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
Platform: C#.net
   I am trying to load a cursor file which is loaded in the resources folder in the application but I am not able to achieve that. I need to change the default cursor to cursor stored in the resource file on mouse hover...  Any suggestions would be appreciated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this blog, it's explained [here](http://psycodedeveloper.wordpress.com/2013/05/26/how-to-load-an-embedded-cursor-from-resources-in-c-windows-forms/) (it's too involved to just grab the code and paste)